# How to combine every 2 rows into 1 row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning, nba-api

I am trying to fix this NBA game detail table.
Every two rows are the same game(GAME_ID) in the table. I want the two rows to be in one row so that the home team and the away team's data will be on the same row.

[image: NBA game details]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set_index and unstack, then flatten headers.

Here is some code I did for baseball games, I had to create my own Game No:

```
# source datafrome
year = '2020'
df = pd.read_excel('https://www.sportsbookreviewsonline.com/scoresoddsarchives/mlb/mlb%20odds%202011.xlsx')
df = df.dropna(how="all").copy()

df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype(int)  # To handle excel float type in some years
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(
    f"{year}" + df["Date"].astype(str).str.rjust(4, "0"), format="%Y%m%d"
)

cols = ["Date", "VH", "Team", "Final", "Close"]
df = df[cols]

df = df[df["VH"].isin(["V", "H"])]

# Flatten teams lines in to games
df["Game No"] = (df["VH"] == "V").cumsum()
df = df.set_index(["Game No", "Date", "VH"]).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.map("_".join)

df = df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Game No       Date Team_H Team_V  Final_H  Final_V  Close_H  Close_V
0           1 2020-03-31    WAS    ATL        0        2      119     -139
1           2 2020-03-31    CIN    MIL        7        6     -110     -110
2           3 2020-03-31    STL    SDG        3        5     -178      158
3           4 2020-03-31    LOS    SFO        2        1     -114     -106
4           5 2020-03-31    NYY    DET        6        3     -152      132
...       ...        ...    ...    ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
2462     2463 2020-10-22    TEX    STL        7       16     -183      163
2463     2464 2020-10-23    TEX    STL        4        0     -171      151
2464     2465 2020-10-24    TEX    STL        4        2     -130      110
2465     2466 2020-10-27    STL    TEX       10        9     -114     -106
2466     2467 2020-10-28    STL    TEX        6        2     -130      110

[2467 rows x 8 columns]
```